# Satisfying Functional Equations

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions ${\rm f}:{\mathbb N}\times{\mathbb N} \rightarrow  {\mathbb N}$ satisfying
$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
a) & {\rm f}\left(n,n\right) & = & n
\\[2mm]
b) & {\rm f}\left(n,m\right) & = & {\rm f}\left(m,n\right)
     \quad\forall\ m,n\ \in {\mathbb N}
\\[2mm]
c) & {{\rm f}\left(m,n + m\right) \over {\rm f}\left(m,n\right)} & = &
{m + n \over n}\quad \forall\ m,n\ \in\ {\mathbb N}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: you might find this useful http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: It's the lcm. http://jsfiddle.net/8qyTz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g(n,m)=\cfrac{nm}{f(n,m)}$

$g(n,n)=\cfrac{n^2}{f(n,n)}=\cfrac{n^2}{n}=n$

$g(m,n)=\cfrac{mn}{f(m,n)}=\cfrac{nm}{f(n,m)}=g(n,m)$

$g(m,m+n)=\cfrac{m(m+n)}{f(m,m+n)}=\cfrac{m(m+n)}{\cfrac{m+n}{n}f(m,n)}=\cfrac{mn}{f(m,n)}=g(m,n)$

---

By recurrence, you can prove $g(m,n \mod m)=g(m,n)$

---

Let $P_n:"\forall k \le n, \forall x \in \Bbb N, g(k,x)=n \land x"$

$P_1$ is true since $g(1,x)=g(1,x-1)=\dots = g(1,1)=1=1\land x$

Suppose $P_n$.

Let $k\le n+1$. Let $x\in \Bbb N$

If $k\le n$, $g(k,x)=k\land x$

If $x\le n$, $g(k,x)=g(x,k)=x\land k = k\land x$

If $k=n+1\le x$, $g(k,x)=g(k,x\mod k)=k \land (x\mod k)=k\land x$ since $x\mod k \le n$

So $P_n \implies P_{n+1}$

By recurrence,

$$\boxed{\forall n,m \in \Bbb N, g(n,m)=n\land m}$$

---

And now, since $nm= (n\land m)(n\lor m)$,

$$\boxed{\forall n,m \in \Bbb N, f(n,m)=n\lor m}$$